# Sudenly, firefox is not opening at Parrot OS

Tags: firefox, apparmor, parrotsec, firejail

I was using few times Parrot OS live booted from RAM or USB as well. Firefox is the web browser built in and my favourite by the way, so I used it. 
Unfortunatelly is not working properly anymore. I cannot open it.

Below is the log I get when I tried to open it from terminal.
There are interesting names of things like AppArmor or Firejail. I think there would be solution in one of them. But what to do next? Where to look for the exact reason?

```
┌─[user@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $firefox
Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/firefox-common.profile
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-devel.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-interpreters.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/disable-programs.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-common.inc
Reading profile /etc/firejail/whitelist-var-common.inc
Parent pid 3232, child pid 3233
Warning: skipping pango for private /etc
Warning: skipping asound.conf for private /etc
Warning: skipping pki for private /etc
Warning: skipping crypto-policies for private /etc
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/ex.da.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/ex.ja.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/ex.pl.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/ex.ru.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/faked.sv.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/fakeroot.sv.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/vi.da.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/vi.ja.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/vi.pl.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/vi.ru.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/view.da.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/view.ja.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/view.pl.1.gz, cannot find inode
Warning fcopy: skipping /etc/alternatives/view.ru.1.gz, cannot find inode
Private /etc installed in 31.55 ms
Post-exec seccomp protector enabled
Seccomp list in: @clock,@cpu-emulation,@debug,@module,@obsolete,@raw-io,@reboot,@resources,@swap,acct,add_key,bpf,fanotify_init,io_cancel,io_destroy,io_getevents,io_setup,io_submit,ioprio_set,kcmp,keyctl,mount,name_to_handle_at,nfsservctl,ni_syscall,open_by_handle_at,personality,pivot_root,process_vm_readv,ptrace,remap_file_pages,request_key,setdomainname,sethostname,syslog,umount,umount2,userfaultfd,vhangup,vmsplice, check list: @default-keep, prelist: adjtimex,clock_adjtime,clock_settime,settimeofday,modify_ldt,lookup_dcookie,perf_event_open,process_vm_writev,delete_module,finit_module,init_module,_sysctl,afs_syscall,create_module,get_kernel_syms,getpmsg,putpmsg,query_module,security,sysfs,tuxcall,uselib,ustat,vserver,ioperm,iopl,kexec_load,kexec_file_load,reboot,set_mempolicy,migrate_pages,move_pages,mbind,swapon,swapoff,acct,add_key,bpf,fanotify_init,io_cancel,io_destroy,io_getevents,io_setup,io_submit,ioprio_set,kcmp,keyctl,mount,name_to_handle_at,nfsservctl,open_by_handle_at,personality,pivot_root,process_vm_readv,ptrace,remap_file_pages,request_key,setdomainname,sethostname,syslog,umount2,userfaultfd,vhangup,vmsplice,
Warning: Cannot confine the application using AppArmor.
Maybe firejail-default AppArmor profile is not loaded into the kernel.
As root, run "aa-enforce firejail-default" to load it.
Child process initialized in 229.51 ms

Parent is shutting down, bye...
┌─[✗]─[user@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ $
```

If I choosed wrong stack-exchange please point me where should I post my question. Regards